# Simple uml diagram to java code

Tags: java, uml

I'm trying to refresh my programming & UML after a summer break. Here's an UMLdiagram I want to convert into Java code.

[image: UML diagram]

Here is my code so far, I'm not sure if its even close to being right.

```
public class Money {
public int money;
public int kronor, öre;
public Money(int kronor, int öre){
}

public int getKronor(){
    return kronor;
}

public int getÖre(){
    return öre;
}

public boolean isPositive(){
    return (money>0);
}

public boolean isNegative(){
    return (money<0);
}

public boolean isZero(){
    return (money==0);
}

public String toString(){

}

}
```

The biggest problem is that I'm not completely sure what these ?methods? mean/do.

```
+Money(in money : Money)
+Money(in kronor : int, in öre : int)
+add(in addend : Money) : Money
+subtract(in subtrahend : Money) : Money
```

It's probably the “in” thing which I'm not sure about!

As a bonus, I would be grateful for any good link or if you could point out some examples of how to implement these methods.

Comment: @OP public int money; and public int kronor, öre; do not exist on your UML Class diagram.  They should be private in code and marked with - in class diagram.

Comment: This is a bit too broad as is for Stack Overflow. If you can ask a more narrow question (perhaps regarding a single method, or something else that a reasonably sized answer could address) we'd love to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
+Money(in money : Money)
```

This is a constructor - it creates a new Money object with the same value as the Money object being passed in.

```
+Money(in kronor : int, in öre : int)
```

This is a constructor - it creates a Money object with the same values passed in (major unit and minor unit (kronor/öre, dollar/cent, pound/pence etc )

```
+add(in addend : Money) : Money
```

This method adds the Money object passed in as an argument to the method, to *this* Money object, and returns a new Money object that is the sum of the two. "Addend" means the object added to this object.

```
+subtract(in subtrahend : Money) : Money
```

Hopefully, by now, you can guess what this one does. "Subtrahend" means the object subtracted from this object.

Answer (score 0):

+Money(in money : Money)

it is a contructor

+Money(in kronor : int, in öre : int)
it is a contructor

+add(in addend : Money) : Money
it is a function

+subtract(in subtrahend : Money) : Money
it is a function

```
public Money(Money money) 
{
// a copy contructor
}

public Money(int kronor, int ore){
// an initializer contructor
}

public Money add(Money addend){
// add the param, return the value
}
public Money subtract(Money subtrahend){
// substract subtrahend and return the value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `in` in front of a method argument means that it is only used for input into the method. Any output back to the caller generated by the method will only be returned via a `return`. If an argument would be preceded by `out` the method itself would alter the argument and after calling it you find its output in the passed object.

Answer (score 0):

+Money(in money : Money) and +Money(in kronor : int, in öre : int) are construcors of your class

+add(in addend : Money) : Money (adding money to the old sum of money)
+subtract(in subtrahend : Money) : Money(substruncting money from the old sum of money)

you can use a  Model Driven UML Tools (http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/)so you just have to add your model and it generates you the classes.